# Compact structure for looking up the number of 1's before a given index

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a (long) string of 0's and 1's, I need to be able to answer quickly queries of the kind: how many 1's in the string precede a given index `i`? One can assume that a 1 is located at index `i`.

I am looking for an *as compact as possible* a data structure that can be computed once for the given string of 0's and 1's and then used as a look-up table to answer quickly the queries as described above.

**Background.** In my particular case, the string of 0's and 1's encodes a grid map (such as in a video game), where 0 denotes an obstacle and 1 denotes a passable location. I store distances from all *passable* locations to one special location in an array. The query corresponds to this: given a passable location (i.e. an index into the string of 0's and 1's), I need to be able to determine quickly the corresponding index into the array of distances.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the bounds on space and time which you _need_ to achieve here? Generally speaking you can't have it both ways, either you get fast queries or space efficiency and the choice of method is a trade-off somewhere in-between.

Comment: do u need to dynamically update the values inside the string and still answer the queries ? If not then just go ahead and count the values for each index, `O(n)` to build it, `O(1)` to answer.  If u want to be able to update the string and still answer queries correctly you can go with segment tree or BST with lazy propagation (if that's the case i can provide expanded answer)

Comment: @Yerken No, but the straightforward approach is too expensive memory-wise -- the look-up table occupies much more space than the string itself.

Comment: @doynax I would like to have O(1) or (at worst) O(log) time for look-ups. The size of the look-up table is of critical importance. Now, I realize it will be O(n) size (where n is the length of the original string), but the factor is very important here and I would like this structure to not occupy much more space than the original string itself. For example, an array of n integers is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: A straightforward and reasonably efficient scheme would be to precalculate the number of preceding bits at block boundaries, say for every 512-bits. That way you get perhaps 6.25% of overhead and a fast worst-case lookup to sum up the remainder, for I'd suggest either a [traditional counting bithack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) or population count intrinsics where available. Of course more efficient compression might easily be able to squeeze the entire bitmap down to a fraction of its original size.

Comment: @doynax First, this should be a reply. Also, the last comment about compressing the whole string is interesting. Would that also work on per-block basis and require un-compressing a block for each query to determine whether a given location is passable? Also, this compression does not seem to affect the size of the data structure for the original question that I asked, does it?

Comment: @doynax What are *population count intrinsics*? I ran a google search, but it did not come up with anything. Some pointer where I can learn about this would be much appreciated.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: It depend on whether or not you still to preserve need the raw bitmap or can afford to work with the compressed representation throughout. A simple example would be a tile-mapping scheme where you store pointers to fixed 16x16 blocks which may be reused, which may or may not be beneficial depending on the nature of your data. Suitable intrinsics may or may not be available for your CPU/compiler. Take a look at [__builtin_popcount](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) or [__popcnt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @doynax I think people will benefit if you compose a reply. Of course, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "succinct indexable dictionaries", which are known by many other names, as well - you can also Google for "succinct rank select". The best solutions have ~5% overhead and constant-time lookups.

"Space-Efficient, High-Performance Rank & Select Structures on Uncompressed Bit Sequences", by Dong Zhou, David G. Andersen, Michael Kaminsky

https://github.com/efficient/rankselect

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/zhou-sea2013.pdf

Comment: Great and even comes with an implementation! There is no documentation, but the interface is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for an as compact as possible a data structure that can be computed once for the given string of 0's and 1's and then used as a look-up table to answer quickly the queries as described above.

This problem is about 6 decades old, and extensively solved. What you're looking at is really just a vector that you could define to be 0 for every value but 1.

If there's very little 1s compared to other values, just go with one of the many *sparse vector representations* that have been around with linear algebra libraries for ever.

You're not giving enough info (like, is your original vector still going to be available, or is it going to be deleted as soon as you have your data storage? I'm going to assume this), but assuming this is a test in solving real world problems on your own rather than choosing the right library to do so:

Knowing *real* computers are nothing like what the algorithms they teach in basic CS were optimized for, the best storage is almost *always* linear storage.

Because counting ones is actually much less time-intense than loading data from RAM into CPU registers, the most effective choice here is the simplest:

Take a wordlength (for example, 64) of your original vector's values, and convert them to bits set (or not set, if the value != 1) in a word; move on to the next word and the next part of your original vector.

Now, to evaluate the number of ones, you would just use a "population count" instruction that practically all CPUs nowadays have – for example, as introduced n x86(_64) by SSE4.1 as `POPCNT`. Use SIMD instructions to generate the sum over adjacent word population counts, and accumulate them up to the point of your index/wordlength. You can, if your problem is both large enough and you have multiple cores with individual caches, also easily divide that algorithm into multiple parallel threads, because there's no mutual dependency. You just add up the sums at the end. Having implemented similar SIMD-optimized code myself, multithreading doesn't pay off if you're limited on CPU cache, because you just end up waiting on RAM with multiple cores.

Anyone telling you to use "runlength" or "linked-list" implementations to encode the distance between 1s neglects the fact that, as mentioned, the problematic part is getting data from RAM, not the actual counting. Memory controllers always fetch a whole memory "row", not just a single value, so that whilst waiting for the first element might easily take the time it does to count the 1s in a couple hundred words worth of wordlength original values each, subsequent accesses to words from the same row are pretty fast.

This is pretty nicely illustrated (partly with invisible graphs) by Bjarne Stroustrup (being one of the evil masterminds behind C++) in [this short lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo).

Comment: I don't see how that addresses the space concern or the performance of large vectors where offline pre-processing is apparently allowed. For the latter concern consider millions of queries over billion-bit vector runs on a static set where a hierarchical bit-counting scheme can be run in logarithmic time, for the former I might consider some form of efficient data-compression supplied with a good model for the two-dimensional the data set. The original question doesn't reveal the size or space limits but I'd assume that they are significant to warrant a question in the first place.

Comment: Your reply is about constructing the data structure quickly. The question is about answering quickly the queries once the structure is computed and even more about the space occupied by the structure. I am not voting down the reply, since it may still be useful for some readers.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no, it doesn't say anything about how to construct that data structure quickly. It just says that a simple bitmap data structure is probably the most space efficient approach, aside from some solutions that aren't actually faster than working on the original data

Comment: anyway, I fully agree with @doynax' comment to the original question – adding a vector containing the running sum has little overhead and makes this significantly faster. So doynax, given that we basically agree on your approach of keeping count in a secondary structure, would you agree with my answer, even for large-scale problems? point is that you need both, a running sum for quick answers at "block" boundaries, and the original placement of 1-elements for correct answers (I thought the running sum thing was obvious, and we were just talking about how to maintain the original info).

Comment: Sorry. I misread. For future readers, it would be nice if you make the reply more explicit and user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** *realised I'd answered the inverse of your problem; this tells you how many 1's come after your position. Just go forward through the bitmap instead of what I suggest below.*

Try creating an int array the length of your bitmap. Working backwards, sum the number of 1's you've seen so far; eg

```
[ 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
```

gives

```
[ - - - - - - - - - - - - - 0 ]
[ - - - - - - - - - - - - 0 0 ]
[ - - - - - - - - - - - 0 0 0 ]
[ - - - - - - - - - - 1 0 0 0 ]
[ - - - - - - - - - 2 1 0 0 0 ]
[ - - - - - - - - 3 2 1 0 0 0 ]
[ - - - - - - - 3 3 2 1 0 0 0 ]
  ...
[ 7 6 6 6 5 5 4 3 3 2 1 0 0 0 ]
```

Now it's just an array lookup, with the added benefit that if you want to know the number between any two points, you can work it out by subtracting one from another.

Comment: This is not compact. See comment #4 on the question.